# Spark cluster with different relative path on Dockerfile both for local and remote reference

Tags: python, pyspark, cluster-computing

I forked a [spark cluster](https://github.com/trouchet/sparkles) work. On file below, step `ADD build/workspace/ ${SHARED_WORKSPACE}/` works fine on building action `master.yml`.

https://github.com/trouchet/sparkles/blob/master/build/docker/jupyterlab/Dockerfile

However, when I run `docker-compose up` locally, it displays the error below and exits the process. I do not know what does it mean, but would be glad to have a reasonable explanation.

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 4fde16fa-4a16-4be6-91bf-37f2e05c57e6::oxwcioymog3hq4pmkri7arkxa: "/workspace": not found

I kept as described above to allow build success status. However, If I need to host, either locally or in production, I change it back to `ADD workspace/ ${SHARED_WORKSPACE}/`.

This is not definitive, as you can see. What do you recommend me to do?